# The norm of a fundamental unit and the narrow Hilbert class field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a real quadratic number field and $\epsilon$ be a fundamental unit. Then apparently the narrow Hilbert class field of $K$ equals the Hilbert class field if and only if $N_{K/\Bbb Q}(\epsilon)=-1$. Why is this the case?

Follow-up question: Does this also hold for complex cubic fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The narrow Hilbert class field is equal to the usual Hilbert class field if and only if the narrow class group is equal to the usual class group, which is the case if and only if the norm of the fundamental unit is $-1$.

For cubic fields, this is clearly not true since $N(-\varepsilon) = - N(\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the narrow class group is equal to the usual class group if and only if the norm of the fundamental unit is $-1$?

Comment: If a generator $\alpha$ of an ideal is not totally positive, then one of $\pm \varepsilon \alpha$ is if $N \varepsilon = -1$.

Answer (score 4):

In the totally real case, the narrow Hilbert class field equals the Hilbert class field exactly when every totally positive unit is a square.

For proof, use Dirichlet's Unit Theorem so see $U/U^2$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$. Then apply Theorem V.1.7 in https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf with conductor the product of all infinite places.